# Triggered E-Mail with Pardot

Tags: trigger, email, triggered-send, pardot

Triggered E-Mail with Pardot based on a business-logic in SF.

We want to send an one-to-one email including dynamic content via Pardot based on a business logic (trigger) from SF.

What is the challenge?
The dynamic content is only available in custom objects in SF and not available in the data model of Pardot.

- Where/how we should define the business logic?
- How we send the trigger to Pardot?
- How we transfer the dynamic content to Pardot to send it with a trigger based email?

With other systems I would do this job either via an automation based on an API Call event or I would enhance the data model of the automation system.

What is the best way with SF and Pardot?

Thanks for your support.
Joachim

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.